# Controling my robot by ROS via Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, quadcopter, communication, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I wrote a program to control my quadrocopter with external microcontroller but i want to move control program from uC into ROS. Base microcontroller of mine robot is ARM but i want to send data into ROS via Arduino and resend it to my robot after regulations etc. I build a catkin workspace and new package "autopilot" but my idea is to create few service nodes for data regulations (aptitude, position etc.) and one client to execute them, is it good idea? I need to send data measured by my modules on quadrocopter into service and from client into quadrocopter nodes but i don't know ho to do it (how send data from rosserial to my workspace/package/example_regulator_node). Now with arduino i only created a HelloWorld and Blink example. I'm very beginner with ROS and i will be very appreciated for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223325/controling-my-robot-by-ros-via-arduino/) by [starcu](https://answers.ros.org/users/25426/starcu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Topics are how data is moved between nodes in ROS. Have a look at the topic tutorials to see how it works.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-01-06**:
If this answered your question please click the tick, to mark it as answered to tidy up the forum